# how to achive javaEE application integration with jms

Tags: jms, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, eai

As am newbie to Enterprise Application Integration Patterns I just understood that it relies on the "Asynchronous Messaging " principle.I can even see that that integration frameworks like Spring Integration are there for this purpose but if I have bunch of **EJB** applications to Integrate can't I just use JMS to achive that ? or have I completely misunderstood the matter.If there example of such integration framework or even a blog post please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try something called open message queue. Opensource message queuing library. one comes embedded with glassfish

[MQ](https://mq.java.net/about.html)
  [2]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPmqikrLNGE  hopefully you can achive what you are looking for as an apporach to integrate ejb applications

Comment: Thank you for the youtube link